# SQL Server: Nested IF 3 level

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to update my control table whenever data is getting inserted or updated on the database. For this, I have created a stored procedure that will get the table name(@TableName), the number of rows inserted(@InsertCount), and the number of rows updated(@UpdateCount)

I tried to implement nested ifs of level 3, but the stored procedure is not working.

Can anyone please help me to understand what can be the issue with the stored procedure?

```
/*
A row is present in the control table   @InsertCount is greater than 0  @UpdateCount is greater than 0  Action
(True/False)    False   False   No action needs to be performed
False   False   True    Insert row in control table and set LastLoadDateTime and DWUpdateDate to current time
False   True    False   Insert row in control table and set LastLoadDateTime and DWInsertDate to current time
False   True    True    Insert row in control table and set LastLoadDateTime, DWUpdateDate, and DWInsertDate to current time
True    False   True    Update row in control table and set LastLoadDateTime and DWUpdateDate to current time
True    True    False   Update row in control table and set LastLoadDateTime and DWInsertDate to current time
True    True    True    Update row in control table and set LastLoadDateTime, DWUpdateDate, and DWInsertDate to current time
*/

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
Create procedure [schema].[StoredProcedure](@TableName nvarchar(50), @InsertCount bigint, @UpdateCount bigint)
as
    DECLARE @JobEndTime datetime;
    DECLARE @IsPresent bit;

    SET @JobEndTime = GETDATE();
    SET @IsPresent = (
        select top 1 COUNT(*)
        from schema.Control_Table
        where TableName = @TableName
    )

    if(@IsPresent = 0)
    BEGIN
        if(@InsertCount <> 0)
        BEGIN
            if(@UpdateCount <> 0)
                insert schema.Control_Table(TableName, LastLoadDateTime, DWInsertDate, DWUpdateDate)
                values (@TableName, @JobEndTime, @JobEndTime, @JobEndTime)
            else
                insert schema.Control_Table(TableName, LastLoadDateTime, DWInsertDate)
                values (@TableName, @JobEndTime, @JobEndTime)
        END
        else
        BEGIN
            if(@UpdateCount <> 0)
                insert schema.Control_Table(TableName, LastLoadDateTime, DWUpdateDate)
                values (@TableName, @JobEndTime, @JobEndTime)
        END
    END
    else
    BEGIN
        if(@InsertCount <> 0)
        BEGIN
            if(@UpdateCount <> 0)
                update schema.Control_Table
                set
                    LastLoadDateTime = @JobEndTime,
                    DWUpdateDate = @JobEndTime,
                    DWInsertDate = @JobEndTime
                where TableName = @TableName
            else
                update schema.Control_Table
                set
                    LastLoadDateTime = @JobEndTime,
                    DWInsertDate = @JobEndTime
                where TableName = @TableName
        END
        else
        BEGIN
            if(@UpdateCount <> 0)
                update schema.Control_Table
                set
                    LastLoadDateTime = @JobEndTime,
                    DWUpdateDate = @JobEndTime
                where TableName = @TableName
        END
    END
```

Comment: Have you tried `ELSE IF`?

Comment: No, I haven't tried that. Can you please explain how I will use it? Also, will it be efficient, or the number of comparisons will increase

Comment: `stored procedure is not working` - you need to be a bit more specific than that. Is it not being accepted (error at creation time)? Are you getting errors at run time? (if so give some examples of inputs and the error you get in response, and if there are any an example of inputs that don't cause errors) Or is there a logic problem? (i.e. no errors, but incorrect result, if so an example of input + what is expect + what happens instead, would likely be useful)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simplify the stored procedure using [CTE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) and [MERGE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/merge-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) statements to avoid needing to use nested IF statements. See this [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=f6d141aa5ea3a7874ddfff24510e698e) for a working example.

Here is the stored procedure code:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [sp] 
(
  @TableName VARCHAR(100)
  , @InsertCount BIGINT
  , @UpdateCount BIGINT
)
AS
BEGIN
  DECLARE @JobEndTime DATETIME = GETDATE()
  
  ;WITH InsertRecords AS
  (
    SELECT @TableName AS TableName
      , IIF(@InsertCount = 0, NULL, @JobEndTime) AS DWInsertDate -- NULL if no INSERTs otherwise, GETDATE()
      , IIF(@UpdateCount = 0, NULL, @JobEndTime)  AS DWUpdateDate -- NULL if no UPDATEs otherwise, GETDATE()
      , @JobEndTime AS JobEndTime
  )
  
  MERGE control_table AS target
  USING InsertRecords AS source ON (target.TableName = source.TableName)
  WHEN MATCHED THEN -- Existing record found for table
    UPDATE SET target.LastLoadDateTime = source.JobEndTime
      , target.DWInsertDate = COALESCE(source.DWInsertDate, target.DWInsertDate) -- If no INSERTs, then use existing value in table
      , target.DWUpdateDate = COALESCE(source.DWUpdateDate, target.DWUpdateDate) -- If no UPDATEs, then use existing value in table
  WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN -- No existing record for table
    INSERT (TableName, LastLoadDateTime, DWInsertdate, DWUpdateDate)
    VALUES (source.TableName, source.JobEndTime, source.DWInsertDate, source.DWUpdateDate)
  ;
END
```

The way this works is the CTE creates a pseudo table that contains one row with columns for the table name, the last load datetime, insert datetime and update datetime. The CTE uses an IIF clause to return GETDATE() if @InsertCount > 0 for the insert date column, and the same for the update date column using @UpdateCount.

This data is then used as the source for the MERGE statement, which basically performs an UPSERT. If an existing row is found for the supplied table name, it updates the date columns and if an existing row isn't found it inserts the new row.

The logic for updating the date columns for existing rows is as follows:

- if the count variable is 0:

  - if there is an existing value in the control table, the existing value is used,
  - otherwise, NULL is used
- if the count is greater than 0:

  - the value from the CTE (GETDATE()) is used.

Comment: Thanks for the stored procedure, but Lastloaddatetime, DWInsertDate & DWUpdateDate are updated even though the InsertCount and UpdateCount are null. Would you please help me to understand why is that happening

Comment: It will be because the IIF clauses are checking if the count variables equal 0. When they are NULL, they don't equal zero. Change the `@InsertCount = 0` to be `COALESCE(@InsertCount, 0) = 0` so that NULL for the count variable behaves the same as 0, and repeat for the @UpdateCount line.

Comment: You will also need to add some logic to deal with LastLoadDateTime, something like `IIF(COALESCE(@InsertCount, 0) = 0 OR COALESCE(@UpdateCount, 0) = 0, NULL, @JobEndTime) AS JobEndTime)` in the CTE and then in the MERGE statement, change the UPDATE line to -: `target.LastLoadDateTime = COALESCE(source.JobEndTime, target.LastLoadDateTime)`